# A general solution to injecting keys to different applications on windows?

Tags: windows, hid

After receiving some feedback on this question: [How to create lParam for WM_CHAR or WM_KEYUP/WM_KEYDOWN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68170277/how-to-create-lparam-for-wm-char-or-wm-keyup-wm-keydown), I`ve started looking for a broader answer to a general solution. One thing I realized that using windows API's might not work for every app and in every case.

My first step in the follow up research was to make an Arduino powered servo to press the keys (yeah the concept is horrible ik).

But that prompted yet another idea, a hardware augmented small numpad keyboard which is also operated by Arduino which was controlled via another usb. This was at least somewhat usable - but still not very.

Then I tried to use Digispark Atiny85 microcontroller which in turn used Digikeyboard library. This solution was much better - but then necessity to have a digispark stuck in your usb port was a bit frustrating.

This made me curious if there are ways to emulate keyboard or any other HID devices using software only? Some brief googling pointed me to Kernel drivers and virtual COM ports, but that seem to be a bit over the top for me to process.

So can that task indeed be achieved by writing a kernel driver? Can it be done in any other manner? In either case are there any pointers which you can give me on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

The [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function can be used to generate keyboard and mouse input. This input goes to the foreground window as if generated by real hardware (but lowlevel hooks can tell that it was software generated). It might not let you generate Ctrl+Alt+Delete nor control a UAC prompt but other than that it should be good enough in most cases. Writing a driver to overcome these limitations is normally not worth it.

There is no general way to generate input to a specific application/window if it is not the foreground window.

If you want to control a specific application you should use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Faking key up/down/char messages with `PostMessage` is not uncommon but it does not always work (the application might be using RAW input, input is not synchronized with real hardware etc.). If you are determined to use this method anyway, make sure you send it to the correct window (the HWND with the keyboard focus, not just the top-level window). Use the Spy++ tool to view the messages to make sure they are going to the correct window.